# Assigning Value to FormGroup and Push to FormArray - Reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Consider the formgroup I have as below:

```
userDetail = new FormGroup({
   name: new FormControl(''),
   addresses:new FormArray([])
})

addressDetail: new FormGroup({
  city: new FormControl(''),
  country:new FormControl('')
})
```

The response I get from API are like:

```
{
  name:"Gayathri",
  addresses:[{
               city:"Chennai", 
               country:"India"
              },{
               city:"Mumbai", 
               country:"India"
              }
}
```

All I am trying now is to assign each object in addresses to addressDetail formgroup and push those formgroup to formarray. The below approach fails and am not sure why so.

Approach 1: 
Consider res is the object containing API response:

```
this.userDetail.patchValue(res) //addresses is blank
 res.addresses.foreach((address)=>{
       this.addressDetail.patchValue(address);
       (<FormArray>this.userDetail.get('addresses')).push(this.addressDetail)
   })
 console.log(this.userDetail.value) //all the two records be city mumbai and country India
```

Approach 2: 
Consider res is the object containing API response:

```
  res.addresses.foreach((address)=>{
          (<FormArray>this.userDetail.get('addresses')).push(this.addressDetail) //assume formGroup is pushed to formarray
       })
 this.userDetail.patchValue(res) //contains addresses
console.log(this.userDetail.value) //all the two records in addresses be city mumbai and country India
```

Please let me know what went wrong and how to resolve.

Comment: You must use a different form group for each address. Not always the same addressDetail FormGroup. And they must contain FormControls, not FormGroups.

Comment: Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: You're trying to use a unique formgroup, `addressDetail`, to store all the addresses. That can't possibly work. You need one form group per address. And each of these form groups must contain FormControls, unlike `addressDetail`, which contains two FormGroups. I'm not sure how I could be clearer than that.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't realise addressDetail had formgroup. i had it as formcontrol only in original code. i made a typo. sorry. how is it possible to have one formgroup per address?

Comment: By creating them on the fly, when you iterate on the array of addresses.

Comment: Thanks much @JBNizet

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  userDetail = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    addresses: new FormArray([])
  })

  addressDetail = new FormGroup({
    city: new FormControl(''),
    country: new FormControl('')
  });

  value = {
  name:"Gayathri",
  addresses:[{
               city:"Chennai", 
               country:"India"
              },{
               city:"Mumbai", 
               country:"India"
              }
]};

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userDetail.patchValue(this.value);
    const addressesFG = this.value.addresses.map(address => {
      return this.fb.group({
        city: [address.city],
        country: [address.country],
      })
    });
    const addressesFormArray: FormArray = this.fb.array(addressesFG);
    this.userDetail.setControl('addresses', addressesFormArray);
    console.log(this.userDetail);
  }


}
```

A stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-myamrb

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks much for your valuable time. i did another workaround like https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vujus3 and this worked too. I liked your approach better.

Comment: ye both work fine i guess push into values its a bad practice. you should use this.addresses = this. userDetail.get('addresses') as FormArray;
  this.addreses.push(this.fb.group({
        city: [address.city],
        country: [address.country],
      }));

Comment: yes yes.. i corrected it then. Thanks loads anthony.

Comment: this has one very important drawback, you lose any reference to the original form array in this case if you had listeners or validators on it. Creates potential for memory leaks. you could just as easily do `addressesFg.forEach(fg => (<FormArray>this.userDetail.get('addresses')).push(fg));` and not risk leaks. Pushing actually is the better practice here for this reason.